# Write form data to OwinRequest in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, owin

As part of a unit test, I'm attempting to create a mock `IOwinRequest` that contains HTTP form data as its body. The code in question works in production (I can successfully read the form data from requests sent through a web browser), but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong with the unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestPostData()
{
    String rawFormData = "test=testValue&test2=testValue2";
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 4 * 1024, true))
        await writer.WriteAsync(rawFormData);

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    Mock<IOwinRequest> requestMock = new Mock<IOwinRequest>();
    requestMock.SetupGet(r => r.Method).Returns("POST");
    requestMock.SetupGet(r => r.Body).Returns(stream);
    requestMock.SetupGet(r => r.ContentType).Returns("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    Assert.IsNotNull(await requestMock.Object.ReadFormAsync());
}
```

The form object returned from the `ReadFormAsync` method is `null`. What am I missing? This is on .Net4.5 and Microsoft.Owin 3.0.1

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You have not setup that method so it would obviously return null when called.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task _TestPostData() {
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() {
         { "test", new[]{"testValue"}},
         { "test2", new[]{"testValue2"}},

    };
    String rawFormData = "test=testValue&test2=testValue2";
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 4 * 1024, true))
        await writer.WriteAsync(rawFormData);

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var formMock = new Mock<IFormCollection>();
    formMock.Setup(_ => _.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => dictionary.GetEnumerator());
    var readableString = formMock.As<IReadableStringCollection>();
    //..setup as desired 

    var requestMock = new Mock<IOwinRequest>();
    requestMock.Setup(_ => _.Method).Returns("POST");
    requestMock.Setup(_ => _.Body).Returns(stream);
    requestMock.Setup(_ => _.ContentType).Returns("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    requestMock.Setup(_ => _.ReadFormAsync()).ReturnsAsync(formMock.Object);

    Assert.IsNotNull(await requestMock.Object.ReadFormAsync());
}
```

But given that this question appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There is not much more in terms of the setup that I can provide in this answer.